# Using C++ library in java

Tags: java, c++, static-libraries

I am new to this forum, so please excuse me if i cannot put my question in a right way.

I want help in using a `C++(.lib and.h)` files in `java`.
I want to use methods of that `.lib` file in my java code .

Prototype of function is like :

```
FunctionXYZ(BYTE *Data1, BYTE *Data2, BYTE *Data3, int Data4);
```

Environment i would be using is centOS.

Thank you in advance

P.S: I do not have source code for this .lib

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: yes i did but did not find appropriate solution

Comment: i get way of using .dll in java but not of using .lib

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To use functions from a `.lib`, you have to create [JNI wrapper functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html) for these library functions, and then link them together with your library into a `.dll`.

**Example:**

1. Assuming you have a function in your C++ library headers with this signature:

   ```
   int example(int a, int b);
   ```
2. Create a function wrapper in C++:

   ```
   JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_MyClass_example (JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jint a, jint b) {
       return (jint) example(a, b);
   }
   ```
3. Link the library and the wrapper into a DLL
4. Create a Java class with the native method:

   ```
   public class MyClass {
       public native int example(int a, int b);
   }
   ```
5. Load the DLL using the `System.loadLibrary` function (or similar)
6. Now you can call the `example` method on an object of `MyClass`

Comment: I do not have source code of that .lib .can i still create jni wrapper.??can you please give me any helpfull link

Comment: You don't need the sourcecode of the `lib`, as a lib is just an object containing the function implementations. When linking with the library, the linker sees these implementations and links them to where you use them in your code. See compiler/linker 101 and my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much.I will proceed with your pointer and will ask if need any clarification

Comment: yes but i didn't found any way of passing BYTE pointer as argument

Comment: Passing a pointer works but makes no sense. You can pass a pointer as a `jint`, but you can NOT dereference it from within Java (that means, it makes no sense, you should only pass values).

Answer (score 1):

you can use JNI technology which enables you to interoperate with native code

please refer to this
http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html

Answer (score 1):

Using JNI is probably the best way to go. Here is a Wikipedia link if you want to read up on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

And here is the documentation for it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html